# Update based on a count of email addresses

Tags: sql-server

I need to set a Lable on a contact record based on finding a duplicate email in the contact table. The duplicate label field is in the contacts_cstm field.

This SP updates all of the records, not just the one submitted.

```
 @EMAIL1 NVARCHAR (100)
 AS
 BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON;
update CONTACTS_CSTM set DUPLICATE_CONTACT_C = 'DUPLICATE' 
 where (select count(EMAIL1)  from CONTACTS as C   
 where C.EMAIL1 = @EMAIL1 ) >1
```

I want to this to update when the count of the contact's email is >1.

Comment: What language is this and what server software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause does not constrain the table you are updating. You need to equate some column of `C` with some column of `CONTACTS_CSTM`,

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I joined the Contacts and Contacts_Cstm tables on the ids, But all of the records still get updated. See my updated SP below. Did I follow what you were suggesting, I feel like I missed something.

Comment: below where? The version in the question doesn't seem to have changed. So I can't offer more advice.